# Python Text file searching

Tags: python, text

I have a LARGE text file that I am needing to pull several values from. the text file has alot of info I don't need. Is there a way I can serach for a specific term that is in a line and return the first value in that line. Please example below

```
text
text text
text
text text text
text text

aaaaa     text      sum

text
text
text
```

I need to search for sum and return the value of `aaaaa`

Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
for Line in file("Text.txt", "r"):
  if Line.find("sum") >= 0:
    print Line.split()[0]
```

`Line.split()` will split the line up into words, and then you can select with an index which starts from 0, i.e. to select the 2nd word use `Line.split()[1]`

Comment: `if 'sum' in Line: ...` will work as well. Also, according to the documentation, `open` is more preferable than `file`.

Comment: great thanks alot. If I want to print the nest value next to aaaa how would I print the values for 0 and 1. print Line.split()[0,1]??? I get an error with this

Comment: Line.split()[1] should do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open(file_path) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'sum' in line:
            print line.split()[0] # Assuming space separated
```

Answer (score 2):

If the text file is indeed big, you can use [mmap — Memory-mapped file support](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) as found in here: [Python Random Access File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999340/python-random-access-file).