# How do I read one and only one byte from a binary file at a specified position?

Tags: python, byte, binary-data, binaryfiles

I am wondering if it is possibly to read one byte at one given position at a time in python. I know about `file.read(`*`any number`*`)`, but I want something that returns the byte I specify and ONLY the byte I specify. If I write: `file.read(10)`, it reads the first 10 bytes of the file.

How do I say *read byte 10 and only return byte 10*? (this must work with all numbers greater than one) also, no classes please!

Comment: try `file.read(10)` followed by `file.read(1)` — will it be enough?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999340/python-random-access-file

Comment: @alf ...well -- that's asking for line-based as opposed to byte-based random access, though the mmap approach the top-rated answer suggests is worth keeping in mind as an alternative to simply seeking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using seek and read, as show below should allow you to read one byte at a given position:

```
f.seek(10)
f.read(1)
```