# How do I read selected lines from a text file with Python

Tags: python, file, notepad

Using Python version 3

I am using the code:

```
f = open("cinema.txt","r")
print(f.read())
```

This then goes on to open the cinema text file. This text file contains 50 lines containing 50 movie titles.

What I want to do is to be able to read for example line 5.
I also want to be able to read for example lines 15-20.
Can someone please advise what is the extra bit I need to add into the code.
I have searched around on the Internet but I can't find an answer that work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999340/python-random-access-file

Answer (score 4):

Use `with open()`, don't use `open()`, it's best practice.

```
data = []
with open("cinema.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.readlines() # readlines() returns a list of items, each item is a line in your file

print(data[5]) # print line 5

for i in range(14, 19):
    print(data[i])
```

Comment: Can you please say why it is best practice to use with?

Comment: Because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31334226/7070779

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use `enumerate` and then check for the line number: Note that `i` starts at i so `i == 4` matches the 5th line.

```
with open('cinema.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 4:
            print(line.strip())
        if 14 < i < 19:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks so much hansaplast - that has saved a lot of time, could you tell me  what extra bit do I need to add?  I want it to be single line spaced when it outputs to file.

Comment: @ellen: you need to `strip()` it to remove the newline. I've adapted the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can record line in the list and display the list slice.

```
f = open("cinema.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
a = 15
b = 20
print("\n".join(lines[a:b + 1]))
```

or

```
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    print('line №' + str(i) + ': ' + lines[i])
```