# How can I mimic a random access file in Python

Tags: python, randomaccessfile

So the course that I am teaching has a requirement to teach the concept of random files - the course content specifies that the files are of a fixed size/length, each location contains a record, and the location in which to store/from which to read is determined through a hashing function (with collisions dealt with in a number of ways). While I am happy with the theory, and the pseudocode that is used to explain this concept, I have to admit, I am struggling with turning this into suitable Python code.

What I need is to be able to

- use a key value and a hashing function to determine a line number in a file (I can do this part)
- jump to that line/location in a specified file
- amend or read the data on that line/at that location

I have seen a couple of mentions of pickling and mmap'ing when doing a bit of research but not sure if this would be the best approach. Very grateful for any guidance.

Comment: `with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f: content = f.readlines()` content is now a list line by line. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Reading a line at an arbitrary location is easy. Updating it is impossible without reading the entire file and rewriting it if the new data is larger than the old.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: Not much randomness in your example.

Comment: Checkout [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) which will map a file into your main memory where you can access it in O(1).

Comment: You may want to fine-tune your terminology. "Random file": a file that contains random data/any single file on your system. "Random **Access** file": a file where you can access every item you want.

Comment: Do you mean random-*access* file? Think about the interface it provides; whether or not the data resides in memory or on disk is secondary, and hardly relevant here.

Comment: See this link and consider using linecache. This will surely fit your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999340/python-random-access-file

Comment: @usr2564301, yes absolutely correct on your part. I was blind copying the syllabus term.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh thanks but no, I know how to do that, I want to be able to open the file, not read everything, jump directly to a specific location and then read the data/line at that location or amend that data/line.

Comment: @chepner - not quite sure what you mean by 'hardly relevant here'?

Comment: @MarkRansom is there absolutely no way to jump to a specified line/point in the file/data and then amend the data without having to read all the data from the file, amend the relevant data and then write all the data back again?

Comment: @RobertFlook If the records are of a *fixed* size, you can indeed jump to a particular record (the offset would be the record size times the record number) and overwrite it with a different record. For an ordinary text file, the size of each line might vary, and the only way to replace one line with a line of different size is to rewrite both the replaced line *and* every line following it (to make room for the extra bytes or to fill the space left by the missing bytes).

Comment: @RobertFlook By hardly relevant, I mean that the *interface* to such a record file and a list is basically the same; both are just sequences of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be divided in two halves:

1. Deciding a (binary?) fixed length format for your records, and being able to serialize/deserialize your data from it; the result must be a fixed length bytestring.
2. Seeking and reading/writing such records on file.

For point 1, there are many possibilities. You can use the `struct` module to generate/read binary data that is generally length.

A way lower technology, but still valid, possibility is just to work with fixed-size text records, each field adequately padded with whitespace or whatever. These can be easily generated with `bytes.format` and split when reading using plain slicing.

Just be careful that, for this to work right, your fields must be formatted/padded adequately as *byte* strings, not unicode ones (if you were to compose the record as a Unicode string and *then* convert it to UTF-8 it may change length, as UTF-8 is a variable length encoding).

As for the second part, it's the easiest: just open the file *in binary mode* (you don't want newline translation to mess with your bytes), use the `seek` method to move to the record you need (using as position the number of record multiplied by its size) to read/write, and then use `read` (passing the record size) or `write` (passing an appropriately sized record).